# gradient for fmin_tnc not working

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, logistic-regression

I am training multiclass logistic regression for handwritting recognition.For function minimization i am using fmin_tnc.
I have implemented gradient function as follows:

```
    def gradient(theta,*args):
        X,y,lamda = args;
        m = np.size(X,0);
        h = X.dot(theta);
        grad = (1/m) * X.T.dot(  sigmoid(h)-y );
        grad[1:np.size(grad),] = grad[1:np.size(grad),] + (lamda/
                        m)*theta[1:np.size(theta),] ;
    return grad.flatten() 
#flattened because  fmin_tnc accepts list of gradients
```

This yields correct gradient values for small set example provided below:

```
  theta_t = np.array([[-2],[-1],[1],[2]]);
  X_t = np.array([[1,0.1,0.6,1.1],[1,0.2,0.7,1.2],[1,0.3,0.8,1.3], 
      [1,0.4,0.9,1.4],[1,0.5,1,1.5]])
  y_t = np.array([[1],[0],[1],[0],[1]])
  lamda_t = 3
```

But when using checkgrad function from scipy its giving error of 0.6222474393497573
I am not able to trace why this is happening.Because of this may be fmin_tnc is not performing any optimization and always gives  optimized parameters equal to initial parameters given.

Answer (score 0):

fmin_tnc function call is as follows:

```
    optimize.fmin_tnc(func=lrcostfunction, x0=initial_theta,fprime = gradient,args= 
   (X,tmp_y.flatten(),lamda))
```

As y and theta passed is of form 1-d array having size(n,) it should be converted to 2-d array having size (n,1).This is because 2-d array form is used in gradient function implementation.
  Correct implementation is as follow:

```
     def gradient(theta,*args):
         #again y and theta reshaped for same reason 
         X,y,lamda = args;
         l = np.size(X,1);
         theta = np.reshape(theta,(l,1));
         m = np.size(X,0);
         y = np.reshape(y,(m,1));
         h = sigmoid( X.dot(theta) );

         grad = (1/m) * X.T.dot( h-y );
         grad[1:np.size(grad),] = grad[1:np.size(grad),] + 
             (lamda/m)*theta[1:np.size(theta),] ;

     return grad.ravel()
```